# convert script from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

i need help i would like to convert this code to python
is there anything online that will turn me into a python? from javascript?
the question is how can I convert it online?

```
const number = parseInt(prompt('od: '));
const range = parseInt(prompt('do: '));

for(let i = 1; i <= range; i++) {
    const result = i * number;

const result1 = result*2;

function d_root(num) {
  return (num % 9) || 9;
}

if((result1.toString().length) == 1){
var z = (result*2)
    console.log(`${number} * ${i} = ${result},*2=vysledek,${z}`);
}
if((result1.toString().length) == 2){
var z = (result*2)
var a =(z.toString().slice(-2,1))
var b =(z.toString().slice(-1))
    console.log(`${number} * ${i} = ${result},*2=vysledek,${z}, ${a+b},${b+a}`);
}
   if((result1.toString().length) == 3){
var z = (result*2)
var a =(z.toString().slice(-0,1))
var b =(z.toString().slice(1,2))
var c =(z.toString().slice(2,3))
    console.log(`${number} * ${i} = ${result},*2=vysledek,${z}, ${a+c+b},${a+b+c}`);
}

if((result1.toString().length) == 4){

var z = (result*2)
var a =(z.toString().slice(0,-3))
var b =(z.toString().slice(1,-2))
var c =(z.toString().slice(2,-1))
var d = (z.toString().slice(3))
    console.log(`${number} * ${i} = ${result},*2=vysledek,${z}, ${a+c+d+b},${a+b+c+d}`);

}}
```

this have in python

```
    def digit_root(n):
        if n == 0: return 0
        return (n - 1) % 9 + 1
n = int(input("od čisla:"))
m = int(input("do čisla:"))

for i in range(1,m + 1):
    result = i*n
    result1 = result*2;
    string = (len(str(result1)))
    if string == 1:
       print(result1)
    if string == 2:
        
    if string == 3:
        
    if string == 4:
```

how do i convert slice? and change the order of the digits?

Comment: Please, check [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @buran basically I want to remake it to python: D but I don't understand javascript

Comment: Do you know what you want to achieve? Do you know [some/enough] python? What prevent you from writing it in python instead of "translate" a javascript you don't understand?

Comment: @buran I don't know just nothing works for me I tried it here I thought there are some tools to convert

Comment: @buran I added a part of the code would you help me with
`(z.toString (). slice (0, -3))`

does it convert to python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you ask.  Some of this is silly.  It splits the number up into digits, then prints the individual digits in the same order.

```
number = int(input('od: '))
nrange = int(input('do: '))

def d_root(num):
    return (num % 9) or 9

for i in range(nrange):
    result = (i+1) * number
    z = result * 2
    zs = str(z)

    if z < 10:
        print( f"{number} * {i+1} = {result}, *2=vysledek,{z}" )

    elif z < 100:
        a = zs[0]
        b = zs[1]
        print( f"{number} * {i+1} = {result}, *2=vysledek,{z}, {a+b},{b+a}" )

    elif z < 1000:
        a = zs[0]
        b = zs[1]
        c = zs[2]
        print( f"{number} * {i+1} = {result}, *2=vysledek,{z}, {a+c+b},{a+b+c}" )

    elif z < 10000:
        a = zs[0]
        b = zs[1]
        c = zs[2]
        d = zs[3]
        print( f"{number} * {i+1} = {result}, *2=vysledek,{z}, {a+c+d+b},{a+b+c+d}" )
```